# determine median of double column r

Tags: r, dataframe, double, median

I have the following dataset

```
> temp6
# A tibble: 120 x 1
      Arithmetic Mean
            <dbl>
 1           0.96
 2           2.09
 3           0.57
 4           0.66
 5           0.92
 6           0.60
 7           0.40
 8           0.42
 9           0.27
10           0.47
# ... with 110 more rows
```

I very badly need the median of this data column, but obviously when I try

```
median(temp6, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in median.default(temp6, na.rm = TRUE) : need numeric data
```

If I attempt to convert this data to 'numeric', that doesn't work either

```
as.numeric(temp6, na.rm=TRUE)
```

or

```
as.numeric(as.character(temp6)
```

gives:

```
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

and

```
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

respectively. I've done enough research to know that neither of these processes will work, but I have not been able to find a workaround of any sort to find the median of these data points. Is there any way to make this happen?

Comment: moved comment to proper location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `?median`

> median(x, na.rm = FALSE, ...)

where

> x an object for which a method has been defined, or a numeric vector
>   containing the values whose median is to be computed.

If it is a `data.frame`, then converting to `vector` can be done with `temp6[,1]`.  As it is a `tibble`, we need `[[`.  Suppose, we do the extraction with `[`

```
temp6[,1]
# A tibble: 10 x 1
#   `Arithmetic Mean`
#               <dbl>
# 1              0.96
# 2              2.09
# 3              0.57
# 4              0.66
# 5              0.92
# 6              0.60
# 7              0.40
# 8              0.42
# 9              0.27
#10              0.47
```

It is still a `tibble`, where as using `[[`

```
temp6[[1]]
#[1] 0.96 2.09 0.57 0.66 0.92 0.60 0.40 0.42 0.27 0.47
```

it is converted to a `vector`

```
is.vector(temp6[[1]])
#[1] TRUE
```

Now, we can get the `median`

```
median(temp6[[1]], na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 0.585
```

Or use the `$`

```
median(temp6$`Arithmetic Mean`, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 0.585
```

#### data

```
temp6 <- structure(list(`Arithmetic Mean` = c(0.96, 2.09, 0.57, 0.66, 
 0.92, 0.6, 0.4, 0.42, 0.27, 0.47)), .Names = "Arithmetic Mean", row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually worked. The sad part is after all this my median is nowhere near the expected result, so there is another problem I must now sort out. At least now I know how to properly convert my DF column to an operable vector.

Comment: @NickBohl You can also use the tidy methods to extract the `median` as showed in the other post

Comment: @NickBohl Please check for anything unusual in your dataset like `Inf` or `-Inf` etc.

Comment: Sadly I've checked for that. I think as I merge the two dataframes and attemp to filter out the columns I need, I'm losing needed data. the problem is these two sets are extremely large (two big for excel) so it's impossible to fact check any of my steps

Comment: @NickBohl  You can use `all(is.finite(temp6[[1]]))`

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr::summarise` is another option.

```
library(dplyr)
temp6 %>% 
  summarise(Median = median(`Arithmetic Mean`, na.rm = TRUE))
```